# Tensorflow 1.4 looking for libcudnn.so.6 rather than libcudnn.so.8

Tags: tensorflow

I am installed tensorflow 1.4.1 on two gpu machines. After installation , one send an error message that

```
ImportError: libcudnn.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

After setting PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH. It works for me.

But the other machine send an error message as

```
ImportError: libcudnn.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

But I don't have such installed. Could someone explain why they looking for different version of libcudnn.so? And how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

download libcudnn.so.6 in https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn. put it to /usr/local/cuda/lib64/ folder and use next commond

```
sudo chmod u=rwx,g=rx,o=rx libcudnn.so.6.5.18
sudo ln -s libcudnn.so.6.5.18 libcudnn.so.6
sudo ln -s libcudnn.so.6 libcudnn.so
```

or change the folder to  /home/username/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/